# Error when running "bee run -e=Godep"

Tags: postgresql, go, beego

I encountered this error message after running "bee run -e=Godeps":

[ORM] registerdb Ping 'default', dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5432: connectex: No connection could be made because the targer machine actively refused it. must have one register Database alias named 'default'

could anyone give me some idea on how to fix it? thanks in advance!

Comment: do you have a database (postgresql?) running on your machine?

Comment: yes i have, i managed to fix the connection problem, now my error message is 
register db Ping 'default', pg: role "apple" does not exist must have one register DataBase alias named 'default'